# Issue pulling data from API - (Paylocity)

Tags: python, api

I am trying to fetch data from API from a tool called Paylocity.

I have managed to generate the access token and trying to connect to their API as below

```
client_id = client_id
client_secret = client_secret
company_id = company_id
prod_auth_url = 'https://apisandbox.paylocity.com/IdentityServer/connect/token'
body_params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'grant_type': 'client_credentials','scope':'WebLinkAPI'})

# Requests can use auth= for basic authentication
auth_response = requests.post(prod_auth_url,auth=(client_id, client_secret), data=urllib.parse.urlencode(body_params))
response = json.loads(auth_response.content)
api_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response['access']}
```

This however returns an error

```
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out by changing the ** auth_response** variable as below

```
auth_response = requests.post(prod_auth_url,auth=(client_id, client_secret), data=body_params)
response = json.loads(auth_response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`auth_response.content` gives you a byte string. Which likely causes the error.  Use `auth_response.text`.

Better even: You don't need `json.loads()` here.
Just do:

```
response = auth_response.json()
```

Comment: thanks for getting back. The error seems to be happening on `data=urllib.parse.urlencode(body_params)` part (the line above). So changing the `auth_response`  is still throwing in that error

Comment: thanks I figured where I was going wrong thanks for your note